# Else and If statements C

Tags: c, if-statement

I just started coding in C, and I can't figure out how to add the idea of *doubles*, where the program detects when a player has rolled the same number on both dies and report it as critical success, critical failure or critical tie. This is a simple dice checker:

```
//Dice Checker Demo 
#include <stdio.h> 

#define SECRET_TARGET 7

int main(void) {
    //read in and store the value of the first die 
    printf("Welcome to Dicechecker!\n"); 
    int dieOne; 
    printf("Please input the value of the first die: ");
    scanf("%d", &dieOne); 

    int dieTwo;
    printf("Please input the value of the second die: ");
    scanf("%d", &dieTwo);

    int total = dieOne + dieTwo;
    printf("The total of the dice roll is currently: %d\n", total);

    if (total > SECRET_TARGET) {
        printf("Skill Roll Successful, Congratulations\n");
    } else if (total == SECRET_TARGET) {
        printf("Close, but not close enough, try again please\n");
    } else if (dieOne == dieTwo && total > SECRET_TARGET) {
        printf("Critical Success! Large Applause\n");
    } else {
        printf("Skill Roll failed, Try Again\n");
    }    

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a better answer, but the way I would do it is just check for equality at the time that the values of both dice are input:

```
if (dieOne == dieTwo)
```

and do your checks as to whether or not they win from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the order of the `if`s

When the first if yields *true* no more ifs will be tested because they're all under the else.

This means that `if (die1 == die2)` will never be tested if sum was greater the SECRET_TARGET.

```
if (total > SECRET_TARGET) {
    //...
} else {
    // here total <= SECRET_TARGET
    if (die1 == die2 && total > SECRET_TARGET) {...}
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no, this is impossible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in your logic: in your *"if-else if-else"* sequence

```
if (total > SECRET_TARGET) {
    printf("Skill Roll Successful, Congratulations\n");
} else if (total == SECRET_TARGET) {
    printf("Close, but not close enough, try again please\n");
} else if (dieOne == dieTwo && total > SECRET_TARGET) {
    printf("Critical Success! Large Applause\n");
} else {
    printf("Skill Roll failed, Try Again\n");
}
```

you perform the check `if (dieOne == dieTwo && total > SECRET_TARGET)` after `if (total > SECRET_TARGET)`. Remember that only one of the branches will be executed so, when `dieOne == dieTwo && total > SECRET_TARGET` also `total > SECRET_TARGET` is true. The latter come first and the second won't even be evaluated.

In order to check your ***double dice condition***, just handle the particular case in your first branch:

```
if (total > SECRET_TARGET) {
    printf("Skill Roll Successful, Congratulations\n");

    /* Particular case: double dice */
    if (dieOne == dieTwo) {
        printf("Critical Success! Large Applause\n");
   }
} else if (total == SECRET_TARGET) {
    printf("Close, but not close enough, try again please\n");
}  else {
    printf("Skill Roll failed, Try Again\n");
}
```

Comment: Apparently the typo has been edited out... I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You discard the possibility of having some predicates correct if you misorder the `if` tests (logic clauses are discussed in the comments to your code, embedded on it):

```
    if (total > SECRET_TARGET) {
        /* here you execute things when total is greater than
         * SECRET_TARGET */
        printf("Skill Roll Successful, Congratulations\n");
    } else if (total == SECRET_TARGET) {
        /* here you have discarded total > SECRET_TARGET, so you know that
         * total <= SECRET_TARGET, and by if clause total has to be equal 
         * to SECRET_TARGET */
        printf("Close, but not close enough, try again please\n");
    } else if (dieOne == dieTwo && total > SECRET_TARGET) {
        /* here you continue discarding, you don't allow total to be
         * > SECRET_TARGET, also you don't allow to be == SECRET_TARGET, so
         * when you say that total > SECRET_TARGET, you are saying that 
         * total <= SECRET TARGET (by the discarding process) and that
         * total > SECRET_TARGET (by the second clause of this if test) and
         * this can never happen. Independently of what the values of the dice 
         * are */
        printf("Critical Success! Large Applause\n");
    } else {
        /* this part is executed only if all of the previous fail, so what
         * you know is that total < SECRET_TARGET, (but both dice can be equal
         * or not, as the third test failed anyway, so any value of the dice 
         * continues to be valid. */
        printf("Skill Roll failed, Try Again\n");
    }
```

In my opinion, if you change order of tests, and put first the test of the two
equal dice, you'll get better results.  Think that your chances using `if`...`else if` are always mutually exclusive (even if, by logic, they are not) and that depends on the order you make the tests.  Go first to the most specific case, and then get less specific cases go tested.  And finally, `else` what to do when nothing matches.

In your case, I should do:

```
if (total > SECRET_TARGET) {
    if (dieOne == dieTwo) {
        printf("Critical Success! Large applause\n");
    } 
 // else { // you have not included this case 
 //        // (total > ST && dice different)
 // }
} else if (total == SECRET_TARGET) {
    printf("Close, but not close enough, try again please\n");
} else {
    printf("Skill Roll failed, Try Again\n");
}
```